# Syntax for filed validation in Drupal 8 Form

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

Hi I am trying to write a custom module in Drupal 8, the requirement of the module is to have a form with some fields in it.

I had wrote form with some field and validation to performed for the input data.

Form fields code looks like this

```
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#size' => 15,
      '#title' => t('Name'),
      '#default_value' => 'user',
      '#maxlength' => 15,
      '#required' => TRUE, 
      '#weight' => 1,
    );
   }
```

Form validation code looks like this

```
   public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

   $name = $form_state->getValue('name');
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
   {
          $form_state->setErrorByName('name', $this->t('Enter a valid name'));
   }
   }
```

According to Drupal docs in  some pages it is documented as

```
 $form_state->setErrorByName('name', $this->t('Enter a valid name'));
```

and in some pages it is mentioned as

```
$form_state->setErrorByName('$name', $this->t('Enter a valid name'));
```

My doubt is what is the correct syntax for the validation?

Observe the differnce between setErrorByName('$name') and setErrorByName('name')

Answer (score 0):

```
$form_state->setErrorByName('name', $this->t('Enter a valid name'));
```

This  is the correct one.

```
      $name = $form_state->getValue('name');
      if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
         $form_state->setErrorByName('name', $this->t('Enter a valid name'));
      }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but what actually does 'name' mean in setErrorByName('name') is it a field name or variable name or some dummy name ?Because even when I write setErrorByName('blabla') or setErrorByName('$name') the validation is performed successfully.

Comment: name from  $form['name']

Comment: Any idea why the validation is working when I write setErrorByName('blabla')?